# Map to png with markers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapbox

I would like export my map (control with mapbox gl js) to png image.
But i d'ont why markers die out.

My exemple https://jsfiddle.net/j2zvwyg9/14/ 
(click on map to export to png)

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  var img = map.getCanvas().toDataURL();
  console.log(img)
  $('body').html('<img src="'+img+'"/>');});
```

`});`;

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with html2canvas
https://jsfiddle.net/j2zvwyg9/17/

```
lol
```

Comment: html2canvas is not a native MapBox export, it's a bad version of a screenshot. Did you find any other way to do this?